# Using SQL variables with INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to use a variable to count the number of rows i have for a specific id, if i use it without inner joins it works perfectly, otherwise no, here is the section without joins

```
    select
                            cd.basis_point bpt,
                            cd.created,
                            @version:=@version+1 version
                        from tbl_class_det cd, (select @version:=1) v
                        where (cd.class_uuid='{$row['uuid']}')
                        and (cd.created>(
                                                        select
                                                            created
                                                        from tbl_class_det
                                                        where (class_uuid=cd.class_uuid)
                                                        order by created asc
                                                        limit 1
                                                    ))
                        order by cd.created asc
```

the section with joins that gives an error:

```
    select c.name,
                            fd.value bpt,
                            fd.created,
                            @version:=@version+1 version
                        from tbl_fee_det fd, (select @version:=1) v
                            INNER JOIN tbl_fee f ON f.uuid = fd.fee_uuid
                            INNER JOIN tbl_class c ON c.uuid = f.class_uuid
                        where (fd.created>(
                                                        select
                                                            created
                                                        from tbl_class_det
                                                        where (fee_uuid=f.uuid)
                                                        order by created asc
                                                        limit 1
                                                    ))
                        order by fd.created asc;
```

Comment: Feel like telling us what the error is? Also this looks like MySQL. You should tag it as such.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'fd.fee_uuid' in 'on clause' ==> but then this column does exist

Comment: Not sure - this being mysql - but using `fd.fee_uuid` in the `ON` when the fd isn't part of that set of tables seems odd. fd is aliased to a table that is the "other side" of a `,` created outer join.

Comment: At a guess, it's an issue with mixing pre-ansi style joins (`, `) and ansi-style joins ` JOIN ` in the `FROM` clause. Try moving the comma join to the end of the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a combination of explicit and implicit joins.  You should not mix the `JOIN` syntax with the comma syntax. If you need to you this then use a subquery similar to this:

```
select name,
    value bpt,
    created,
    @version:=@version+1 version
from
(
    select c.name,
        fd.value,
        fd.created,
        f.uuid
    FROM tbl_fee_det fd
    INNER JOIN tbl_fee f 
        ON f.uuid = fd.fee_uuid
    INNER JOIN tbl_class c 
        ON c.uuid = f.class_uuid
) f, (select @version:=1) v
where (created>(select created
                   from tbl_class_det
                   where (fee_uuid=f.uuid)
                   order by created asc
                   limit 1))
order by created asc;
```